# Google Spreadsheet Query IF statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I made a cell where I can enter the company name and my query filters the results to only show records from that specific company.

Example 1: Here I type 'TestCompany1':

[image]

---

Example 2: Here I type 'TestCompany2':

[image]

---

What I wish to achieve is that when the cell value is blank, it shows all companies. Now it shows all empty. How can I change the query to also allow this?

[image]

Comment: by sharing a copy of your sheet, you can increase the chance of getting an answer under 15 minutes (usually it takes time to recreate the whole scenario from images)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use `IF` statement then:

```
=IF(B3<>"", QUERY(Company_overview!A2:L, 
 "where B = '"&B3&"' 
    and L >= datetime '"&TEXT(TODAY()-B4, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"' 
    and L <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),      "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"'", 1), 
 QUERY(Company_overview!A2:L, 
 "where L >= datetime '"&TEXT(TODAY()-B4, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"' 
    and L <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),      "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"'", 1))
```

or maybe:

```
=QUERY(Company_overview!A2:L, 
     "where "&IF(B3<>"", "B = '"&B3&"' and ", )&"
            L >= datetime '"&TEXT(TODAY()-B4, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"' 
        and L <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),      "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"'", 1)
```